# Draw a polygon in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, polygon

I need to use an arrow picture's in my website,so i decide to draw it with line by asp.net,but i do not know how to do it.
how to draw a polygon with asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a javascript method, that draw Polygon and register it from Asp.Net side with [Register methods](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19484/Register-Client-script-in-ASP-NET)

```
function DrawPolygon()
{
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   context.fillStyle = '#f00';
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(0, 0);
   context.lineTo(100,100);
   context.lineTo(50, 100);
   context.lineTo(10, 10);
   context.closePath();
   context.fill();
}
```